Pgbouncer: got packet 'E' from server when not linked
Does anyone knows what this error below means? We running pgbouncer 1.21 on centos using transaction pooling mode.
2024-04-29 15:00:02.378 CST [9680] WARNING S-0x197b028: db/user_a@10.0.0.1:5432 got packet 'E' from server when not linked
2024-04-29 15:00:02.379 CST [9680] LOG S-0x197b028: db/user_a@10.0.0.1:5432 closing because: server conn crashed? (age=2409s)

We faced this warning after enabling min_pool_size.

I think there should be log messages on the Postgresql server log file which will inform this situation.

One case I know of would be setting idle_connection_timeout. The server log will say "FATAL:  terminating connection due to idle-session timeout", but the pgbouncer log will only give the warning you indicated with no further explanation.

@jjanes Thanks for pointing out about PostgreSQL logs, that was very helpful indeed, we had a cronjob killing idle sessions at scheduled period which was conflicting with pgbouncer min_pool_size setting but only if the session is idle for long time.
